# Mail is not Going in PHP

Tags: php

i am not able to send email in php,Any one help me to identify
    i am not able to send email in php,Any one help me to identify where i am wrong.After filling form All details has to go a specified email.but here it is displaying else condition.So,Please help me to solve this problem.
    i am not able to send email in php,Any one help me to identify where i am wrong.After filling form All details has to go a specified email.but here it is displaying else condition.So,Please help me to solve this problem.
    i am not able to send email in php,Any one help me to identify where i am wrong.After filling form All details has to go a specified email.but here it is displaying else condition.So,Please help me to solve this problem. where i am wrong.After filling form All details has to go a specified email.but here it is displaying else condition.So,Please help me to solve this problem.

```
<?php

$englishname = $_REQUEST['firstname'].'&nbsp'.$_REQUEST['lastname'];
$arabicname = $_REQUEST['firstnamearabic'].'&nbsp'.$_REQUEST['lastnamearabic'];
$education = $_POST['education'];
$ar_education = $_POST['educationarabic'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$country= $_POST['parent_cat'];
$city= $_POST['cit_cat'];
$area= $_POST['area'];
$mobilenumber= $_POST['mobileno'];
$doorno= $_POST['doorno'];
$phone= $_POST['phoneno'];
$street= $_POST['street'];
$apartment = $_POST['apartment'];
$experience = $_POST['experience'];
$postalcode = $_POST['postelcode'];
$landmark = $_POST['landmark'];

if(isset($_POST['requesttype'])&&$_POST['requesttype'] == 'addEmployee')
          {

$to = 'arundsti@gmail.com';
$subject = 'NEW DOCTOR REGISTRATION DETAILS-FIND A DOCTOR';



       $from    = $_REQUEST['email'];      

    // mandatory headers for email message, change if you need something different in your setting. 
    $headers  = "From: " . $from . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "CC: info@findadoctorsa.com\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 


$message = "Name in English: $englishname.\r\n";
$message .= "Name in Arabic: $arabicname.\r\n";
$message .= "Education: $education \r\n";
$message .= "Education in Arabic: $ar_education \r\n";
$message .= "Email: $email \r\n";
$message .= "Country: $country \r\n";
$message .= "City: $city \r\n";
$message .= "Area: $area \r\n";
$message .= "Mobilenumber: $mobilenumber \r\n";
$message .= "DoorNumber: $doorno \r\n";
$message .= "PhoneNumber: $phone \r\n";
$message .= "Street: $street \r\n";
$message .= "Apartment: $apartment \r\n";
$message .= "Experience: $experience \r\n";
$message .= "Postalcode: $postalcode \r\n";
$message .= "Landmark: $landmark \r\n";

$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if($sent){ ?>
    <script>
    alert('Your Details received Successfully...We will Touch with you shortly');
    </script>
<?php   
}
else {?>
    <script>

    alert('Sorry Problem in Submitting Details,Please try Again');
    </script>
<?php   
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you doing locally in your computer or on a server?

Comment: Server only i am executing this code

Comment: Do you have a SMTP service enabled?

Comment: But for other modules mails are going fine...only in this it is not going

Comment: try validating your input - do you know for a fact that `$email = $_POST['email'];` is valid?

Comment: yes it is right only, i am getting all my form data

Comment: You should look at the postfix logs on your server otherwise you won't understand why the email is not sent